# Can anyone explain this line in this geometry file?

Tags: matlab

I have this geometry file, which I don't understand. Can anyone explains what this line does?

```
             boundary = [0,0.25,0.5,0.75;
             0.25,0.5,0.75,1;
              1,1,1,1;
              0,0,0,0];
             varargout{1} = boundary(:,bs);
```

I need to modify this file so that I replace the striaght lines, representing the edges by curved lines but first I need to understand what each line means .. This is the m.file Thanks

```
function varargout = rechteckgeometrie(varargin)

  length = 0.05315;
  length2 = 0.07;
  width = 0.575;

  switch nargin
   case 0
    varargout{1} = 4;
  case 1
    bs = varargin{1};
    boundary = [0,0.25,0.5,0.75;
                0.25,0.5,0.75,1;
                1,1,1,1;
                0,0,0,0];
    varargout{1} = boundary(:,bs);
case 2
    if isempty(varargin{1}) && isempty(varargin{2})
        varargout{1,2} = [];
    else
        bs = varargin{1};
        s = varargin{2};

       boundary = [0,width,width,0,0;
           0,0,length2,length,0];

        varargout{1} = (bs-4*s).*reshape(boundary(1,bs),size(bs))+...
            (4*s+1-bs).*reshape(boundary(1,bs+1),size(bs));
        varargout{2} = (bs-4*s).*reshape(boundary(2,bs),size(bs))+...
            (4*s+1-bs).*reshape(boundary(2,bs+1),size(bs));       
    end
otherwise
    disp('Wrong number of input arguments');
end
%-----------------
figure; clf;
pdegplot('rechteckgeometrie', 'edgeLabels', 'on');
```

Comment: It is really complicated to understand what the function actually does since it lacks function description and the input arguments are abbreviated with `bs` and `s`. The guess is that for one argument you select some of the columns and that will give you some shape. Else you can use 2 arguments to select the shape's side length as a multiple of an already defined rectangle. I am not sure what the function will be used for, so I cannot say what the expected answer is. Just that it is a boundary of something that none can tell except you. `varargout` defines the output arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement assigns a `4x4` matrix with the specified 16 values to a variable called `boundary`.

The second statement (`varargout{1} = boundary(:,bs);`) sets the return value of `rechteckgeometrie` to the `bs`<sup>th</sup> column of `boundary`.